# How to check Kafka cluster connectivity and topic availability status using Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I want to implement 2 separate methods to return boolean value based on Kafka cluster connectivity and then Kafka topic availability status.

However the [KafkaAdmin/Admin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#topicCheckTimeout) provides methods to return topic list and descriptions at runtime. But I am not able to finalize the best approach to proceed further for both connectivity and topic availability check using Spring Boot.

```
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class KafkaAdminstrator{

    private final AdminClient adminClient;

    public boolean isKafkaClusterExists(String bootstrapServer){
        //Kafka cluster connectivity check 
    ...
    }

    public boolean isTopicExists(String topic){
        //Kafka topic availability check
        //adminClient.describeTopics(topic);
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The AdminClient is exactly what you want. Please clarify why that isn't working for you

Comment: adminClient.describeTopics(Collections.singleton(topic)).allTopicNames().get().containsKey(topic); is that the only way to check it? if not I want to find out the simplest way possible of doing it.

Comment: That's the only way, via Java AdminClient, yes. The alternative would be to run `kafka-topics` shell script (which calls the same method) and parse its output. I think you meant `all().get`, not `allTopicNames()`? Also, you could just check non empty since the map is more or less guaranteed to have that key you've described, if the describe was successful

Comment: It looks like `all()` is deprecated since version 3.1, and what's the usage of default method `adminClient.listTopics().names().get()`?

Comment: Okay, I was looking at 2.4 javadoc... What do you mean by default method?

Comment: `default ListTopicsResult listTopics(), ListTopicsResult listTopics​(ListTopicsOptions options)` Ref: [Interface Admin](https://kafka.apache.org/30/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html)

Comment: What exactly is your question? You don't need to list all topics when you can only describe one of them

Comment: I'm able to proceed with the `adminClient.describeTopics()` method. Thanks for the information.

Comment: Glad to hear. Feel free to accept the below answer using the checkmark next to the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass an AdminClient instance into both methods. The client already is defined with a bootstrap server property, so you wouldn't set a new one for the cluster check (`describeCluster` or `describeTopics` will both make a network request to the cluster, thus checking connectivity)

If you want to really check cluster health, you'd expose JMX metrics on the servers, not from a client